# Grey Squares Appearing in Compositor in Blender 2.9

Tags: compositing-nodes

When using the compositor in Blender 2.9x, there are grey boxes in the background whenever Backdrop is enabled. They appear in every version of 2.9 that I've used on my machine but don't appear in any versions of 2.8.

[image: Text]
(Boxes)

[image: Text]
(No Boxes)

It's not a huge issue, but it's a little annoying since they tend to shift around whenever I zoom or pan the background image. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there any way to get rid of them?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Is your graphics card up to date?

Comment: It appears to be. I've got an Intel(R) UHD if anyone's interested. Honestly, my computer's not great in the graphics department, and I suspected that might be the problem, but as the issue doesn't appear in 2.8 I'm hoping there's something I can do within 2.9 to address it.